# How to move useSelector to separate file and import from it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component, example:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const tests = useSelector(state => state.waterfall.tests)
  return <div>{value}</div> 
}
```

I want to move use selector to a separate file.
Question - if I move useSelector to file as const
`export const testsValue = () => { useSelector(state => state.waterfall.tests) }`
and import it in component - does it will work or I will have problems/side effects because Hooks must be defined on top level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is in React called a [Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

there are a few recommendations with using custom hooks:

- call the custom hook only in a react component or other custom hook
- don't call it conditionally
- the hook name should start with "use"

otherwise it should work without any problems.